# Can someone working in USA with H1B visa get PR of Canada?

Tags: immigration, canada, resident-permit, h1-visa

If I have a H1B visa and working in USA, can I apply and get PR of Canada? If so, how much time will it take considering that I would be staying in USA?

Comment: "how much time will it take considering that I would be staying in USA?" Do you mean to say that you intend to continue to live in the US even after being approved for permanent residency in Canada?

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the Immigration Canada website?
There is explained which programs exists to immigrate. I suggest to check out what applies to you.

https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada.html